# Splitting XML into smaller XML files of specified size

Tags: java, xml

I am pretty new with XML, and bad news are that I have XML of the following structure:

```
<record>
   <record_id>200</record_id>
   <record_rows>
        <record_row>some text</record_row>
        .................................
   </record_rows>
</record>
```

Number of record rows is different in each record, so, each record is pretty different in size. My task is to split the file (which is more than 1GB) into separate xml files of specified size. Which parser would be the best?  Also, i guess i should employ some record picking strategy to get closer to target size (and i can't imagine any at the time taking into account input file size and unpredictability of next records size)

The only hope is on you, my friends. How would you approach this?

Comment: Does the size have to be exact? (If so do the files need to be _valid_ XML)?

Comment: files should be as close as possible to the specified size, but not exact. Files should be valid XMLs

Comment: "Which parser" is an opinion question. So is "how would you approach this" actually... but my own recommendation would be to adapt the standard SAX read-in-and-write-back-out example to recognize that each time it exits a `<record>` it should check output document length and, if too close to the boundary, terminate the document and start a new one.

Comment: Note that the only way you're going to be certain not to overshoot the target size while still doing streaming processing would be to do this as two-pass -- one to pick the break points, and another to actually divide up the records. The alternative involves loading the whole document into memory before writing out the chunks.

Comment: Well, you could write a sax parser with a string writer as buffer. On every time you append something to the buffer, check the string size and decide if you are going to write the file and flush the buffer or if you're going to use the new data in the next file. Remember that there may be a row bigger than your desired file (not likely)

Comment: Mid air collision ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your record rows aren't larger than the desired size of your individual files, you can use a SAX Parser to read the file sequentially and count the characters read, storing the data read so far in a buffer. When the character count reaches a value which is near your size limit, it will create a new file containing only the records read so far, reset the buffer and character count, and will continue reading another set, until the limit is reached again, and so on. In the end you will have a set of files which is roughly the same size (except for the last one, which might be smaller) and that contain the same data.

To use a SAX parser you will need an executable containing the code below:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;

public class SAXReader {

    public static final String PATH = "src/main/resources";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
        reader.setContentHandler(new DataSaxHandler()); // need to implement this file
        reader.parse(new InputSource(new FileInputStream(new File(PATH, "data.xml"))));
    }
}
```

Your XML file is stored in `src/main/resources/data.xml` (relative to where you run the application). You might want to change that.

If the split files are to be well formed XML, they should also have a root element, and probably preserve information such as `record_id` so you can know from which record they came from. I added an attribute `part` containing a sequential number ordering the file fragments. The resulting files will look like this:

**data_part_1.xml**

```
<record part='1'><record_id>200</record_id><record_rows><record_row>...</record_row><record_row>...</record_row> ... <record_row>...</record_row></record_rows></record>
```

**data_part_2.xml**

```
<record part='2'><record_id>200</record_id><record_rows><record_row>...</record_row><record_row>...</record_row> ... <record_row>...</record_row></record_rows></record>
```

...

**data_part_n.xml**

```
<record part='n'><record_id>200</record_id><record_rows><record_row>...</record_row><record_row>...</record_row><record_row>...</record_row><record_row>...</record_row></record_rows></record>
```

Where 'n' is the number of files created.

The SAX ContentHandler implementation which achieves this result is shown below. You might want to change the `DIRECTORY` and `MAX_SIZE` constants:

```
import java.io.*;
import org.xml.sax.*;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

class DataSaxHandler extends DefaultHandler {

    // Change this to the directory where the files will be stored
    public static final String DIRECTORY = "target/results"; 

    // Change this to the approximate size of the resulting files (in characters(
    public static final long MAX_SIZE = 1024;


    public static final long TAG_CHAR_SIZE = 5; //"<></>"

    // counts number of files created
    private int fileCount = 0;

    // counts characters to decide where to split file
    private long charCount = 0;
    // data line buffer (is reset when the file is split)
    private StringBuilder recordRowDataLines = new StringBuilder();

    // temporary variables used for the parser events
    private String currentElement = null;
    private String currentRecordId = null;
    private String currentRecordRowData = null;

    @Override
    public void startDocument() throws SAXException {
        File dir = new File(DIRECTORY);
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdir();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) throws SAXException {
        currentElement = qName;
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("record_rows")) { // no more records - save last file here!
            try {
                saveFragment();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw new SAXException(ex);
            }
        }
        if (qName.equals("record_row")) { // one record finished - save in buffer & calculate size so far
            charCount += tagSize("record_row");
            recordRowDataLines.append("<record_row>")
                              .append(currentRecordRowData)
                              .append("</record_row>");
            if (charCount >= MAX_SIZE) { // if max size was reached, save what was read so far in a new file
                try {
                    saveFragment();
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    throw new SAXException(ex);
                }
            }
        }
        currentElement = null;
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException {
        System.out.println(new String(ch, start, length));
        if (currentElement == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (currentElement.equals("record_id")) {
            currentRecordId = new String(ch, start, length); 
        }
        if (currentElement.equals("record_row")) {
            currentRecordRowData = new String(ch, start, length);
            charCount += currentRecordRowData.length(); // storing size so far
        }
    }

    public long tagSize(String tagName) {
        return TAG_CHAR_SIZE + tagName.length() * 2; // size of text + tags
    }

    /**
     * Saves a new file containing approximately MAX_SIZE in chars 
     */
    public void saveFragment() throws IOException {
        ++fileCount;
        StringBuilder fileContent = new StringBuilder();
        fileContent.append("<record part='")
                   .append(fileCount)
                   .append("'><record_id>")
                   .append(currentRecordId)
                   .append("</record_id>")
                   .append("<record_rows>")
                   .append(recordRowDataLines)
                   .append("</record_rows></record>");
        File fragment = new File(DIRECTORY, "data_part_" + fileCount + ".xml");
        FileWriter out = new FileWriter(fragment);
        out.write(fileContent.toString());
        out.flush();
        out.close();

        // reset fragment data - record buffer and char count
        recordRowDataLines = new StringBuilder();
        charCount = 0;
    }

}
```